# add image as div with javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to add an image as an element into my webpage. I am unable to do so. There are instructions on how to preview an image, but I was unable to find a solution.

What I want it to do is to add a div with an image into the webpage and keep loading it with different images. So after I add image 1, I would load image 2 under image 1 in the same webpage.

html body code:

```
<input type='file' id='getval' /><br/><br/>
<span onclick="readURL()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
<div id="myUL"></div>
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // grabs image
    var file = document.createElement('image');
    file.src = document.getElementById('getval').files[0];
    // creates div & assigns id
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'item';

    // adds file to div
    file.type = 'image';
    div.appendChild(file);

    //adds item
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```

edit1*
I think adding the output of the code I want to display would be better inside the html document.

javascript generates html code inside document:

```
 <div style="background-image":url("image");"><div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script

```js
count = 0;
function viewImage(){
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#image');
                if (imagefile.files && imagefile.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
var content = '<img id="temp_image_'+count+'" style="border: 1px solid; width: 107px;height:107px;" >';
document.querySelector('#all_images').innerHTML += content;
document.querySelector('#temp_image_'+count).setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
                    };  reader.readAsDataURL(imagefile.files[0]);
                  this.imagefile = imagefile.files[0];
                  count++;
                }else{
                    console.log("Image not selected");
                }
   }
```

```html
<div id="all_images">
</div>
<input id="image" name="image" type="file" onChange="viewImage()">
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was not what I asked for. I asked for images that would be loaded into the webpage as a new individual element.

Comment: Yes please~ There are scripts for what you posted elsewhere, I got a base of my code from other posts and tried to modify the code to fit what I want. However, I was unable to do so :(

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, although pay attention to the comment at line 3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var file = document.createElement("img");
file.setAttribute("src", document.getElementById('getval').files[0]); //You can use HTML5 File API here
file.setAttribute("height", "250");
file.setAttribute("width", "250");
var divTocreate = document.createElement('div');
divTocreate.id = 'item';
divTocreate.appendChild(file);
document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(divTocreate);
</script>
```

Comment: hi, I tried your code. However, when I added it to the function, it was close to doing the job, adding a new image down the list. But, it failed to read the image file and inspecting the image, the tag came out as <img src="[object File]">. So the image was not read.